# How to reduce pixels in polygons by calculating mean in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, pixel

I'm new at Google Earth Engine environment. I would like to create a time series chart with many large polygons but I get this error: `Error generating chart: Error in map(ID=20191205T005916_20191211T151317): Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 25359892, but maxPixels allows only 10000000.`
I would like to reduce these pixels by calculating a mean value for each polygon.

```
//Crear geometría para una región específica (Área de interés) a partir de coordenadas.
//De manera alternativa, se puede crear una capa de 'MultiPoint' o 'MultiPolygon' para el área de interés.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-12.9419, 32.6294, 42.0776, 64.7974]);

//Añadir unidades espaciales para el análisis de series multitemporales
//De manera alternativa: crearlos como 'MultiPolygon' o 'MultiPoint'.
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection('users/kovcsdniel962/URAU_C_2018');
var styleParams = {
  fillColor: '00000000',
  color: '#232323',
  width: 0.5,
};

 var spatialunits = featureCollection.style(styleParams);
 Map.addLayer(spatialunits, {}, 'Urban Areas');

 //Filtrar los datos
 var filter = ee.Filter.inList('CNTR_CODE', ['IT']);
 var filteredArea = featureCollection.filter(filter);
 Map.addLayer(filteredArea, {color: 'green'}, 'filteredArea');

 var newroi = filteredArea;

 //Datos Sentinel 5P para NO2. Fecha 1.
 var N02 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
   .filterDate('2019-12-05', '2019-12-22'); //Selección de periodo temporal

 //Datos para columna NO2 Troposférico
 var SentinelNO2Tropo = N02
   .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
   .filterBounds (roi);
 var NO2TropoData = ee.Image(SentinelNO2Tropo.median());
 var NO2TropoClip_date1 = NO2TropoData.clip (roi);
 Map.addLayer (NO2TropoClip_date1, {
   max: 0.0002, 
   min: 0.0, 
   palette: ["black", "blue", "purple", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "red"]}, 
   'NO2 Tropospheric Date 1');
 Export.image.toDrive({
   image: NO2TropoClip_date1.select("tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density"),
   description: 'NO2_Tropospheric_Date1',
   scale: 1100,
   region: roi});

 // Crear una gráfica para columna NO2 Troposférico.
 var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
   imageCollection: SentinelNO2Tropo.select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density'),
   region: newroi,
   reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
   scale: 30
  })
  .setOptions({title: 'Tropospheric NO2 over time. Date 1.'});

  // Representar la gráfica en la consola.
  print(chart);
```

Comment: If I increase the scale number in the chart variable it creates the chart correctly.

Comment: Hi, I tried to run your code but your assets aren't public. Please [share your assets](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/asset_manager#sharing-assets) so that others can recreate the full issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `ui.Chart.image.series` does not have the option to increase the reducing limit of 1e7 pixels. A workaround could be to "manually" reduce each image with `reduceRegion` where you can play with `maxPixels` parameter. Your image collection would then be converted to a feature collection with which you could use `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature` to obtain the same chart.

Just replace your `var chart ...` with the following code:

```
var fts = SentinelNO2Tropo.select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
    .map(function(img) {
        var  dict = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), geometry: newroi, scale: 30, maxPixels: 1e13})
        return ee.Feature(null, dict.combine({time: img.get('system:time_start')}))
    })
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(fts, 'time')
    .setOptions({title: 'Tropospheric NO2 over time. Date 1.'})
print(chart)
```

Although this might work, it would take more time for GEE to process the large number of pixels involved in the reduction.